# Load local and different browser c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, webforms

I have a website with links to some intranet pages. Some of these will open best in certain browsers. If I run the code locally this works fine.

From firefox this will open internet explorer and work fine.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
info.Arguments = "http://google.com";
Process.Start(info);
```

After published firefox will just reload the page again not even go to google.com. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Is the path to iexplore.exe present in the other machines in the same location ? Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: You can call just `iexplore.exe`

Comment: Explore.exe path is the same. I even tried with iexplore.exe that does not work either.

Comment: I tried both, but nothing works. I use firefox.